# phonegap build:Not getting registration Id on iOS 9.1 push notification

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to build a simple app using latest pushnotification plugin. I am using Phonegap build. But I am not able to get the registration Id on iOS 9.1 but it is working on iOS8. Check below code

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "12345679"
            },"ios":  {
                "alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"
             }, "windows": {  }
          });


        push.on('registration', function(data) {
            alert("got registration id");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            localStorage.setItem("deviceToken", data.registrationId);
          });

        push.on('notification', function(data) {
            // data.message,
            // data.title,
            // data.count,
            // data.sound,
            // data.image,
            // data.additionalData
          });

        push.on('error', function(e) {
            // e.message
            alert(e.message);
        });
```

**Config.xml**

```
  <gap:plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" source="npm" version="1.4.2" />
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-5.2.0" />
  <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle"/>
```

Comment: I am using Phonegap build.

Comment: Your last edit overwrote good edits on this question, but I think that might have been a problem with your browser cache. When editing it is worth refreshing your browser before you start, and consulting [the edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33737668/revisions) afterwards to ensure your intended edit was the only one that has been recorded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of this problem,
Actually it's not certain thing but it's combination of more than one factor

For client side make sure to use the latest version of the push plugin found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) which is 1.4.2 (till now)

here is the a sample of client side code

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "12345679"},
     "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

For server side and Xcode project :

1- be sure to use Xcode 7.1.1 (latest stable version till now)

2- be sure to create APNS Production NOT DEVELOPMENT certificate then download it

[image]

3- drag it or open it with keychain access expand it and export the private key as yourAppNameKey.p12

[image]

4- then we need to generate the pem file for the certificate,So via terminal write :

```
 openssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform der -out yourAppNameCert.pem
```

Note : ins the last step we used the certificate which we downloaded in step 2

5- now we will Convert the private key’s .p12 file into a .pem file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out yourAppNameKey.pem -in yourAppNameKey.p12
```

Note : you will be asked to enter the password you used to export the private key and insert a pass phrase and confirm it to use in the server side code

6 - Finally we will combine the certificate and key into a single .pem file:

```
cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
```

[here is a sample of the server side code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0zVybqvfI8dY0JwYW1mWENEcWc/view?usp=sharing)

Hope it works with everyone .. Thanks

Comment: I am using Phonegap build. How to use APNS cer in phonegap build ? I am using plain dev cert to sign my app not the apns cert in the phonegap build. I have updated my question as well

Comment: APNS certificate is not interfering with the dev or production certificates
APNS certificate will be used to generate ck.pem which will be used in the server side and you can use your dev_cert to build with phone gap
All steps in my Answer is far from the main phonegap project, you need your developer account and your keychain only